# MySQL sum Selected row

Tags: mysql

I would like to sum multiple row selected id my code is

```
SELECT sum(yellow) AS yellow,
       sum(orange) AS orange,
       sum(red) AS red,
       sum(blue) AS blue,
       sum(green) AS green,
       sum(purple) AS purple
FROM main
WHERE ID IN ('180 , 182')
```

but get the first id only not sum both .

Answer (score 0):

modify your query as

```
SELECT sum(yellow) AS yellow,
       sum(orange) AS orange,
       sum(red) AS red,
       sum(blue) AS blue,
       sum(green) AS green,
       sum(purple) AS purple
FROM main
WHERE ID IN ('180' , '182');
                 ^   ^
                  Place single quotes here
```

[More about MySQL IN clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)

Comment: Explain what you are changed?

Comment: @Sadikhasan the original post had some ' missing in his sql statements taht he added (Naveen put the locations where the ' were missing now via edit into his answer.

Comment: But user said display `first id only` how it possible?

Comment: @Sadikhasan ah the user said he only gets and that that is the problem (as far as I understand the question of his). and the problem causing this were the missing single quotes (and I take it Naveen also interpreted the question that way).